# Count rows with consecutive dates within PANDAS groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[This is the closest to what i'm looking for that I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753823/how-to-identify-consecutive-dates)

Let's say my dataframe looks something like this:

```
d = {'item_number':['K208UL','AKD098008','DF900A','K208UL','AKD098008']
     'Comp_ID':['998798098','988797387','12398787','998798098','988797387']
     'date':['2016-11-12','2016-11-13','2016-11-17','2016-11-13','2016-11-14']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to count the amount of times where the same `item_number` and `Comp_ID` were observed on consecutive days.

I imagine this will look something along the lines of:

```
g = df.groupby(['Comp_ID','item_number'])
g.apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.iloc[i,'date'].shift(-1) - x.iloc[i,'date'] == 1].count())
```

However, I would need to extract the day from each date as an int before comparing, which I'm also having trouble with.

```
for i in df.index:
    wbc_seven.iloc[i, 'day_column'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(df.iloc[i,'date'],'%Y-%m-%d').day
```

Apparently location based indexing only allows for integers? How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I would need to extract the day from each date as an int
>   before comparing, which I'm also having trouble with.

#### Why?

To fix your code, you need:

```
consecutive['date'] = pd.to_datetime(consecutive['date'])
g = consecutive.groupby(['Comp_ID','item_number'])
g['date'].apply(lambda x: sum(abs((x.shift(-1) - x)) == pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='D')))
```

Note the following:

1. The code above avoids repetitions. That is a basic programming principle: [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)
2. It converts 1 to `timedelta` for proper comparison.
3. It takes the absolute difference.

---

Tip, write a top level function for your work, instead of a `lambda`, as it accords better readability, brevity, and aesthetics:

```
def differencer(grp, day_dif):
    """Counts rows in grp separated by day_dif day(s)"""
    d = abs(grp.shift(-1) - grp)
    return sum(d == pd.to_timedelta(day_dif, unit='D'))
g['date'].apply(differencer, day_dif=1)
```

---

### Explanation:

It is pretty straightforward. The dates are [converted to `Timestamp` type](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps), then subtracted. The difference will result in a [`timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html), which needs to also be compared with a `timedelta` object, hence the conversion of 1 (or `day_dif`) to `timedelta`. The result of that conversion will be a Boolean Series. Boolean are represented by 0 for `False` and 1 for `True`. Sum of a Boolean Series will return the total number of `True` values in the Series.

Comment: I got this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Well, obviously, you need to convert your 'date' column to `Timestamp` type. Use this `consecutive['date'] = pd.to_datetime(consecutive['date'])` before grouping. I'll edit in the answer as well.

Comment: Awesome! from my initial round of QA it looks like this is working beautifully. I wasn't as far off as I'd thought. Would really appreciate if you could add a bit of an explanation as to what is happening in your code.  @Kartik

Comment: I added an explanation. Also, simplified a little, you don't need to index again with the Boolean Series returned by the comparison. A simple `sum` would suffice your needs. And you were definitely not far off, good job on that :-). Please accept answer, and upvote if you find it useful. Those controls are on the left of the answer.

Comment: I don't have the rep points to up-vote yet but def exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: Well then, accept this as answer at least. You do that by clicking the check mark under the voting arrows... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use pivot tables to count the number of times a `Comp_ID` and an `item_number` were observed on consecutive days.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'item_number':['K208UL','AKD098008','DF900A','K208UL','AKD098008'],'Comp_ID':['998798098','988797387','12398787','998798098','988797387'],'date':['2016-11-12','2016-11-13','2016-11-17','2016-11-13','2016-11-14']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).sort_values(['item_number','Comp_ID'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['delta'] = (df['date'] - df['date'].shift(1))
df = df[(df['delta']=='1 days 00:00:00.000000000') & (df['Comp_ID'] == df['Comp_ID'].shift(1)) & 
        (df['item_number'] == df['item_number'].shift(1))].pivot_table( index=['item_number','Comp_ID'],
           values=['date'],aggfunc='count').reset_index()
df.rename(columns={'date':'consecutive_days'},inplace =True)
```

Results in

```
  item_number    Comp_ID  consecutive_days
0   AKD098008  988797387                 1
1      K208UL  998798098                 1
```