# PANDAS count consecutive dates in a row from start position

Tags: python, pandas

This is an example of the data frame i'm working with:

```
 d = {'item_number':['bdsm1000', 'bdsm1000', 'bdsm1000', 'ZZRWB18','ZZRWB18', 'ZZRWB18', 'ZZRWB18', 'ZZHP1427BLK', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1427', 'ZZHP1414', 'ZZHP1414', 'ZZHP1414', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115WNTR', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE', 'WRM115SCFRE'], 'Comp_ID':, [2454, 2454, 2454, 1395, 1395, 1395, 1395, 3378, 1266941, 660867, 43978, 1266941, 660867, 43978, 1266941, 660867, 43978, 1266941, 660867, 43978, 43978, 43978, 43978, 1197347907, 70745, 4737, 1197347907, 4737, 1197347907, 70745, 4737, 1197347907, 70745, 4737, 1197347907, 4737, 1197487704, 1197347907, 70745, 23872, 4737, 1197347907, 4737, 1197487704, 1197347907, 23872, 4737, 1197487704, 1197347907, 70745]
'date': ['2016-11-22', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-21', '2016-11-21', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-18', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-22', '2016-11-21', '2016-11-21', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-20', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-19', '2016-11-19']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'd like to count consecutive observations starting from 2016-11-22 that there are grouped by Comp_ID and item_number.

Essentially, what I am looking to do, is count how many days in a row there is an observation counting back from todays date for each Comp_ID and item_number. (this example was put together on the 22nd of Nov) Consecutive observations observed weeks/ days prior to today are not relevant. Only sequences like today... yesterday... the day before yesterday... and so on are relevant.

I got this to work on a smaller sample, but it seems to be getting tripped up on a larger data-set.

```
d = {'item_number':['KIN005','KIN005','KIN005','KIN005','KIN005','A789B','A789B','A789B','G123    H','G123H','G123H'],
'Comp_ID':['1395','1395','1395','1395','1395','7787','7787','7787','1395','1395','1395'],
'date':['2016-11-22','2016-11-21','2016-11-20','2016-11-14','2016-11-13','2016-11-22','2016-11-21','2016-11-12','2016-11-22','2016-11-21','2016-11-08']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
d = pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')

df = df.sort_values(['item_number','date','Comp_ID'],ascending=False)

g = df.groupby(['Comp_ID','item_number'])
sequence = g['date'].apply(lambda x: x.diff().fillna(0).abs().le(d)).reset_index()
sequence.set_index('index',inplace=True)
test = df.join(sequence)
test.columns = ['Comp_ID','date','item_number','consecutive']
g = test.groupby(['Comp_ID','item_number'])
g['consecutive'].apply(lambda x: x.idxmin() - x.idxmax() )
```

This gets the desired result for this data-set of:

```
Comp_ID  item_number
1395     G123H          2
         KIN005         3
7787     KIN005         2
Name: consecutive, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is very similar to: [link to related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666628/count-rows-with-consecutive-dates-within-pandas-groupby) Just not quite there

Comment: What do you mean? The number of consecutive days going backwards? So you would identify '2016-11-22','2016-11-21','2016-11-20' as a chain and count is as 2?

Comment: @AlexG correct!

Comment: @kartik maybe youve got this one too

Comment: just subtract 1 from your answer?

Comment: @maxymoo this is going to be done on a much larger scale, across multiple sellers/ item numbers. i need a way to count how many days in a row from todays date. this example was put together yesterday.

Comment: @maxymoo is right. you're counting the total number of consecutive values. you just need to subtract one to find the number of subsequent dates.

Comment: @maxymoo is not right. that is just saying 3-1=2. i've edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

***setup***
fixed your data

```
d = {'item_number':['KIN005','KIN005','KIN005','KIN005','KIN005'],
 'Comp_ID':['1395','1395','1395','1395','1395'],
 'date':['2016-11-22','2016-11-21','2016-11-20','2016-11-14','2016-11-13']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

---

***solution***

```
d = pd.Timedelta(1, 'D')
df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=False)
consecutive = df.date.diff().fillna(0).abs().le(d)
idx_loc = df.index.get_loc(consecutive.idxmin())
df.iloc[:idx_loc]
```

[image]

---

your number of consecutives since most recent is simply

```
idx_loc - 1

2
```

Comment: could you possibly throw in an explanation as to what is happening in your code? would love to be able to apply the logic in other situations. cheers. looks great!:)

Comment: having trouble applying this to a dataset that's more similar to what i'm actually working with. i've edited the sample. would love if you could take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some nice functional methods that will probably work for you. But if you want ugly ... I can give you ugly.

```
date = df.iloc[0, 1]
count = 0

consecutive_obs = []
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):

    if row[1] == date - datetime.timedelta(days=1):
        print(row)
        count += 1
    else:
        if i > 0:
            consecutive_obs = consecutive_obs + [count]*(count + 1)
            count = 0        
    date = row[1]

consecutive_obs = consecutive_obs + [count]*(count + 1)

df['consecutive_obs'] = consecutive_obs
```

Comment: this looks promising! i was thinking it'd take a loop to evaluate if the timedelta is = 1 day then continue. imagine i could use a while loop or something idk. i'll play with this and get back to you. appreciate the feedback!