# Counting days in a column groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Inspired by this question-

[Count rows with consecutive dates within PANDAS groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666628/count-rows-with-consecutive-dates-within-pandas-groupby)

Dataframe

```
d = {'item_number':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
     'Comp_ID':['Be','Be','Be','De','Ce','Ce','Ce','Ce'],
     'date':['2016-11-12','2016-11-13','2016-11-14','2016-11-18','2016-11-13','2016-11-16','2016-11-17','2016-11-18']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to print all the rows which for the same item_number and Comp_id are occurring consecutively day wise.

The solution given in that question was-

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
g = df.groupby(['Comp_ID','item_number'])
g['date'].apply(lambda x: sum(abs((x.shift(-3) - x)) >=pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='D')))
```

The solution provided isn't working if the consecutive days are occurring if preceded by nonconsecutive days and not upto my desired format.

My desired output-

```
item_number Comp_ID date
0   A   Be  2016-11-12
1   A   Be  2016-11-13
2   A   Be  2016-11-14
5   B   Ce  2016-11-16
6   B   Ce  2016-11-17
7   B   Ce  2016-11-18
```

error-

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    724             try:
--> 725                 result = self._python_apply_general(f)
    726             except Exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    741     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 742         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
    743 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    236             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
--> 237             res = f(group)
    238             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in curried_with_axis(x)
    623             def curried_with_axis(x):
--> 624                 return f(x, *args, **kwargs_with_axis)
    625 

TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    638             try:
--> 639                 return self.apply(curried_with_axis)
    640             except Exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    814     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 815         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
    816 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    736                 with _group_selection_context(self):
--> 737                     return self._python_apply_general(f)
    738 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    741     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 742         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
    743 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    236             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
--> 237             res = f(group)
    238             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in curried_with_axis(x)
    623             def curried_with_axis(x):
--> 624                 return f(x, *args, **kwargs_with_axis)
    625 

TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    724             try:
--> 725                 result = self._python_apply_general(f)
    726             except Exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    741     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 742         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
    743 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    236             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
--> 237             res = f(group)
    238             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in curried(x)
    626             def curried(x):
--> 627                 return f(x, *args, **kwargs)
    628 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in diff(self, periods)
   2550         """
-> 2551         result = algorithms.diff(com.values_from_object(self), periods)
   2552         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in diff(arr, n, axis)
   1976         else:
-> 1977             out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
   1978 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    641                 try:
--> 642                     return self.apply(curried)
    643                 except Exception:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    814     def apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 815         return super().apply(func, *args, **kwargs)
    816 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    736                 with _group_selection_context(self):
--> 737                     return self._python_apply_general(f)
    738 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    741     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 742         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
    743 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
    236             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
--> 237             res = f(group)
    238             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in curried(x)
    626             def curried(x):
--> 627                 return f(x, *args, **kwargs)
    628 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in diff(self, periods)
   2550         """
-> 2551         result = algorithms.diff(com.values_from_object(self), periods)
   2552         return self._constructor(result, index=self.index).__finalize__(self)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in diff(arr, n, axis)
   1976         else:
-> 1977             out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
   1978 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    651                     try:
--> 652                         return self._aggregate_item_by_item(name, *args, **kwargs)
    653                     except (AttributeError):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    565         raise AttributeError(
--> 566             "%r object has no attribute %r" % (type(self).__name__, attr)
    567         )

AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-359-81e3625b4519> in <module>
      2 slot_with_over_projection_1k = slot_with_over_projection_1k.sort_values(['CITY','OPS_ZONE','SLOT','DT']) #if neccesary
      3 slot_with_over_projection_1k.loc[slot_with_over_projection_1k.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(slot_with_over_projection_1k['DT']))
----> 4          .groupby(['CITY','OPS_ZONE','SLOT'])['DT']
      5          .diff()
      6          .ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    652                         return self._aggregate_item_by_item(name, *args, **kwargs)
    653                     except (AttributeError):
--> 654                         raise ValueError
    655 
    656         return wrapper

ValueError:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
g = (df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date']))
       .groupby(['item_number','Comp_ID'])['date'])

df2 = pd.concat([g.diff().rename('previous_diff'),
                 g.diff(-1).abs().rename('next_diff')],
                axis = 1,sort = True)

df_filtered = df[df2.notna().any(axis = 1) &
                 df2.eq(pd.Timedelta(days = 1)).any(axis = 1)]
print(df_filtered)
  item_number Comp_ID        date
0           A      Be  2016-11-12
1           A      Be  2016-11-13
2           A      Be  2016-11-14
5           B      Ce  2016-11-16
6           B      Ce  2016-11-17
7           B      Ce  2016-11-18
```

**EDIT**

```
n=3
# df = df.sort_values(['item_number','Comp_ID','date']) #if neccesary
df.loc[df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date']))
         .groupby(['item_number','Comp_ID'])['date']
         .diff()
         .ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
         .groupby([df['item_number'],df['Comp_ID']])
         .cumsum()
         .groupby(['date',df['item_number'],df['Comp_ID']])['date']
         .transform('size')
         .ge(n)]


#  item_number Comp_ID        date
#0           A      Be  2016-11-12
#1           A      Be  2016-11-13
#2           A      Be  2016-11-14
#5           B      Ce  2016-11-16
#6           B      Ce  2016-11-17
#7           B      Ce  2016-11-18
```

**try:**

**1**

```
n=3
# df = df.sort_values(['item_number','Comp_ID','date']) #if neccesary
df.loc[df.assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date']))
         .groupby(['item_number','Comp_ID'])
         .diff()
         .ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
         .groupby([df['item_number'],df['Comp_ID']])
         .cumsum()
         .groupby(['date',df['item_number'],df['Comp_ID']])['date']
         .transform('size')
         .ge(n)]
```

---

**2: select only columns you need**

```
n=3
# df = df.sort_values(['item_number','Comp_ID','date']) #if neccesary
df.loc[df[['item_number','Comp_ID','date']].assign(date = pd.to_datetime(df['date']))
         .groupby(['item_number','Comp_ID'])
         .diff()
         .ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
         .groupby([df['item_number'],df['Comp_ID']])
         .cumsum()
         .groupby(['date',df['item_number'],df['Comp_ID']])['date']
         .transform('size')
         .ge(n)]
```

Comment: how can I change it to a variable as in 3 consecutive 4 consec etc?

Comment: I am getting a huge error...can you help please when I am running it on actual data?

Comment: try `2` an `1`. Have you passed argument to `diff`: `TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`?